# Access to Array of objects elements :I am trying to print the submitter with highest number of metric :which is redness or plumpness

Tags: javascript

```
const judgeVegetable=function(vegetables,metric){
   var max=0,position=0,i=0;
if(metric ==='redness'){
 for(i=0;i<vegetables.length;i++){
  //for(let veg in vegetables) {
     if(vegetables.redness[i] > max){
       max=vegetables.redness[i];
       position=i;
     }
    }
}
```

If I call the function with the parametres below then ;

```
const vegetables = [
  {
    submitter: 'Old Man Franklin',
    redness: 10,
    plumpness: 5
  },
  {
    submitter: 'Sally Tomato-Grower',
    redness: 2,
    plumpness: 8
  },
  {
    submitter: 'Hamid Hamidson',
    redness: 4,
    plumpness: 3
  }
]

const metric = 'redness';

console.log(judgeVegetable(vegetables, metric));
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE :Old Man Franklin (my code is giving error and i don't know where)

Answer (score 0):

Running your code as is gives the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

That's because you forgot the closing brace for the function definition. Procure to use proper indentation and spacing on your code, that way you will spot these kind of errors easily. Example:

```
const judgeVegetable = function(vegetables,metric) {
  var max = 0, position = 0, i = 0;

  if(metric ==='redness') {
  for(i = 0; i < vegetables.length; i++) {
    //for(let veg in vegetables) {
      if(vegetables.redness[i] > max) {
        max=vegetables.redness[i];
        position=i;
      }
    //}
  }
}
```

Notice also that I included the disabled `for` with its corresponding disabled closing brace.

But fixing that alone won't produce desired results yet, because there are other errors in your code. I walk you through:

You have the second `for` loop disabled via comment, let's remove it completely so it doesn't confuse you.

You cannot access `vegetables.redness[i]` because `vegetables` is the array, not `redness`, which is a field inside an object inside the `vegetables` array. So let's fix that and remove the disabled `for` loop:

```
const judgeVegetable = function(vegetables,metric) {
  var max = 0, position = 0, i = 0;

  if(metric === 'redness') {
    for(i = 0; i < vegetables.length; i++) {
      if(vegetables[i].redness > max) {
        max = vegetables[i].redness;
        position = i;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now the code doesn't produce any errors, but it also doesn't return anything, you need to return the value found, so:

```
const judgeVegetable = function(vegetables,metric) {
  var max = 0, position = 0, i = 0;

  if(metric === 'redness') {
    for(i = 0; i < vegetables.length; i++) {
      if(vegetables[i].redness > max) {
        max = vegetables[i].redness;
        position = i;
      }
    }
  }
  return vegetables[position].submitter;
}
```

And now is working :) Well, almost, you still have to write the code to select the proper answer if the metric is `plumpness`. Which leads me to a simplification to your code which also solves this issue: remove the if and access the proper field by using the `metric` parameter:

```
const judgeVegetable = function(vegetables, metric) {
  var max = 0, position = 0, i = 0;
 
  for(i = 0; i < vegetables.length; i++) {
    if(vegetables[i][metric]> max) {
      max = vegetables[i][metric];
      position = i;
    }
  }
  return vegetables[position].submitter;
}
 
console.log(judgeVegetable(vegetables, 'redness')); // Old Man Franklin
console.log(judgeVegetable(vegetables, 'plumpness')); // Sally Tomato-Grower
```

Other suggestions for you to consider:

- there's no need to assign a function to a variable (`const` in this case), you can define the function the traditional way:

```
function judgeVegetable(vegetables, metric) { ...
```

Or with the new arrow functions syntax:

```
const judgeVegetable = (vegetables, metric) => { ...
```

- the `i` parameter can be declared and initialized in the `for` loop, so no need to do it beforehand
- don't use `var`, use `const` and `let` appropriately

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification!It worked and I learned a lot.I am new to coding.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Array.reduce()` method, or sort the array then get the first element.

For what's wrong with your code, `[i]` should be after `vegetables` instead of `vegetables.redness`. `vegetables` is an array and does not have a property named `redness`. You are also missing a closing `}` for `if(metric ==='redness'){` and missing the return value.

```js
const vegetables = [
  {
    submitter: 'Old Man Franklin',
    redness: 10,
    plumpness: 5
  },
  {
    submitter: 'Sally Tomato-Grower',
    redness: 2,
    plumpness: 8
  },
  {
    submitter: 'Hamid Hamidson',
    redness: 4,
    plumpness: 3
  }
];

const metric = 'redness';

//reduce method
let max = vegetables.reduce((acc,cur)=>{
  if(!acc)
  {
    return cur;
  }
  if(cur[metric] > acc[metric])
  {
    return cur;
  }
  return acc;
},null);
console.log(max.submitter);

//sort method (this mutate the array)
max = vegetables.sort((a,b)=> b[metric] - a[metric])[0];
console.log(max.submitter);

//Your method
const judgeVegetable = function(vegetables,metric){
  var max=0,position=0,i=0;
  if(metric ==='redness'){
    for(i=0;i<vegetables.length;i++){
       if(vegetables[i].redness > max){
         max = vegetables[i].redness;
         position = i;
       }
    }
  }
  return vegetables[position].submitter;
}

console.log(judgeVegetable(vegetables,metric));
```

Comment: The op is not asking for other (complex) methods to get desired result, but where is the error, and probably will want to know why too. By reading the code one can also presume is starting to learn Javascript, so throwing in a `.reduce()` may not be what he/she needs now

Comment: Thanks it is working now!New to coding haven't learned.reduce() yet.